# allow users to upload files firebase and admin can view the file firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

so I'm using the firebase sample
https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firestore-web#1
and I was trying to expand my knowledge. If I want a user to be able to upload a file, then the admin can see the file the user uploaded, how would I do that? I want to stay with just firebase. Could I have a user upload the file, but it gets marked as a post, then make the post only visible to the admin? How would I do that? I'm pretty new with this so I would need some help.

Comment: For sure you can do that. What have you tried so far to achieve that?

Comment: nothing. im pretty new to this kind of stuff, so i dont where to to even start.